# XML not well formed

Tags: html, xml

When I put the end tag on link in head of html page, the W3C Validator shows well-formed.

But then when I validate HTML it says "Stray end link tag".

How can I validate both HTML and XML at same time?

Comment: Which version of HTML are you trying to validate against; which doctype are you using? Is XTHML an option?

Answer (score 0):

[Appendix C](http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/#guidelines) of XHTML 1.0 recommends syntax like

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="foo.css" />
```

That is, the XML “self-closing” empty element tag syntax, with a space before the slash `/`. The space is actually not needed any more (browsers that required it have become extinct), so you can also write

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="foo.css"/>
```

This works on all browsers. Formally, you should not use it HTML 4.01 (see a longish explanation in [Empty elements in SGML, HTML, XML, and XHTML](http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/html/empty.html)), and it may cause a validation error, depending on context (for `link`, it does).

There’s no way to make the same document both a conforming HTML 4.01 document and a conforming XHTML 1.0 document. Normally, there is no need either.

In HTML5, it’s different: the “self-closing” syntax is allowed both in HTML serialization and in XML (XHTML) serialization.

Comment: As an additional pointer, in XHTML elements that _can_ have content between their tags should use opening and closing tags: `<script src="..."></script>`. Elements that can never have content between their tags should use self-closing tags: `<link rel="..." href="..." />`.